# php: Logout button won't change to login

Tags: php, html, session

So I am trying to set header such that if the user has already logged in, the log in link changes to log out and if the user has logged out, It should change from logout to login. I was able to change login to logout but then, even if the user logs out, the link still remains on "Logout" instead of changing back to login. Here's my header part of php that is supposed to change login to logout and logout to login :-

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])): ?>
<a href="" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Login</a>
<?php else: ?>
<a href="" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Log out</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and here is my code for the the logout page. Whenever a register used clicks on logout, it is supposed to destroy the session and clear the `$_session` and show a message to the user that he has successfully logged out. What am I doing wrong? BTW I have gone through a lot of similar questions but didn't find a satisfying answers

```
<?php include 'header.php';?>
<?php
SESSION_START();
unset($_SESSION['username']);
session_destroy();
echo "<br>";
echo "You are successfully Logged Out!";
echo "<br>";
?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION)` and see what is the result

Answer (score 0):

From your code, the condition for the login/logout buttons is incorrect, it should be:

```
<?php if ( ! isset($_SESSION['username'] ) ): ?>
<a href="" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Login</a>
<?php else: ?>
<a href="" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Log out</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Also, I noticed that your script did not contain any authentication and verification to confirm if the user is real and exists in your user's database table. Anyone can setup a username session and bypass your script easily. This is really important when you're on a live server.

Comment: The session is not active then, call `session_start()` at the top of your script and  check if the username session exists: `var_dump( isset( $_SESSION['username'] ) )`

Comment: so whenever I log in, the var_dump( isset( $_SESSION['username'] ) ) returns back bool(true) and whenever I log out, it returns bool(false) and yet the login status wont change

Answer (score 0):

condition is error

```
  <?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
      echo `<a href="" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Login</a>`;
    }else{
     echo `<a href="" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Log out</a>`;
    }
   ?>
```

and session never started  SESSION_START(); replace with session_start();

Comment: this just made the entire button disappear from the screen :/